# Discount cart in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am using codeigniter cart for online commerce, and i still confuse how to make coupon which automatically update the total cart when coupon code found for an items.

Thanks

Comment: You coupon code is in db. if Coupn code is submitted check db and get the value of discount. Then check total of cart/product and make some calculation and deduct it from the total.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try it. Any suggestion how if coupon only work for specific item?

Answer (score 1):

Each and every coupon is stored in Database. So in database table there are some important fields.

1. Coupon Code `#ex 007AbC0098`
2. Value of coupon `#ex 3%`
3. If its for product then product ID `#ex 25`

---

First user add items to cart and the at show cart option you will allow to add the coupon. So when user add the coupon, **check if coupon is valid**. If its valid

1. Get the value of the coupn
2. Get the session cart total value `$this->cart->format_number($this->cart->total());`
3. And make the calculation in local
4. Add that to privet session and before check pay, check the session has some of values.
5. If yes deduct it from total, else proceed to Payment.

---

If its only for and product. **Get the product id from coupon table, and do calculation and proceed**.

---

**References**

1. [CodeIgniter Shopping Cart Sample - FormGet.com](https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-shopping-cart/)

Comment: Thanks, i try first before i mark as answered. Help me if i found a problem later.

Comment: @SamsulArifin oki. Try ur best

Answer (score 0):

You can do a for each loop through each item in the basket.
change the price of each item manually (percentage off), this percentage can be taken from the DB.
Once the price has been changed, you can:
$this->cart->update($data);  where $data is the name of the array that was iterated over.